# Запрос UPDATE не обновляет данные в таблице БД C#

Tags: c#, winforms, запрос

Не могу понять почему так происходит, я вроде бы всё правильно написал.

```
private void dataGridView3_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        accessGeneralData = true;

        try
        {
            if (dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dsGeneralData.Tables["GeneralData"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    string cellDataGrid = dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Наименование"].Value.ToString();
                    string cellDataSet = dsGeneralData.Tables["GeneralData"].Rows[i]["Наименование"].ToString();

                    if (cellDataGrid == cellDataSet)
                    {
                        int boxes = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
                        int sold = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
                        int elemRemains = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
                        int remains = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
                        int finRemains;

                        elemRemains = boxes - sold;

                        if (elemRemains < 0)
                        {
                            remains = remains + elemRemains;

                            for (int g = 1; remains <= 0; g++)
                            {
                                remains++;
                                elemRemains++;

                                if (elemRemains < 0)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Невозможно вычесть из остатка недостающие число, так как остаток меньше нуля.",
                                        "Внимание!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        finRemains = elemRemains + remains;

                        SqlCommand updateGeneralData = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE GeneralData SET Остаток @Ост WHERE Код = @Код", connection);

                        updateGeneralData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ост", finRemains);
                        updateGeneralData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Код", i);
                        updateGeneralData.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        SqlCommand updateProduct = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE Product SET Остаток = @Ост WHERE Наименование = @Наименование", connection);

                        updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ост", finRemains);
                        updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Наименование", cellDataSet);
                        updateProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Внимание!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну может коммит нужно делать? Где вы вообще коннекшен открываете и где закрываете? Может он у вас дальше живёт ещё, транзакция открыта и обновление висит незакоммиченое?

Comment: Не держите никогда соединение открытым просто "потому что". Используйте `using (SqlConnection connection = new(**)) { connection.Open(); *someCode*}`. Данная конструкция автоматически закроет соединение в конце `}` using-а. А так, смотря на ваш код - может соединение у вас не открыто. Слишком много логики привязано к одной кнопке. Распределите этот большой кусок по маленьким методам с говорящими названиями (пример: создайте метод `UpdateProduct`, который будет обновлять только product)

Comment: Я коннекшн не закрываю, он у меня висит на протяжении всей программы. Разве это как-то вредит выполнению?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` возвращает количество обработанных строк таблицы, а что возвращает ваш? Отлаживать пробовали? Если 0, то это значит, что запрос ничего не задел в базе.

Comment: Попробуйте параметры запроса типа `@Код` написать латиницей `@code`. Они в самом запросе не участвуют, они нужны только для формаирования полного SQL запроса и в базу не попадают, поэтому все равно как вы их назовете.

Comment: @aepot, у меня помимо этого запроса в остальных также реализованы переменные с использование кириллицы, но я уже и решил проблему. Как оказалось, всё крылось в том, что я не закрывал connection с БД, но я вся же не совсем понимаю как на уровне классов это работает и почему connection Необходимо закрывать.

Comment: А вы попробуйте вместо закрытия соединения диспозить команду после того как она отработает. Почитайте про IDisposable, его нельзя игнорить так, как это делаете вы. Написал в ответе, как именно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команды надо диспозить

```
using (SqlCommand updateGeneralData = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE GeneralData SET Остаток @Ост WHERE Код = @Код", connection))
{
    updateGeneralData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ост", finRemains);
    updateGeneralData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Код", i);
    updateGeneralData.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

using (SqlCommand updateProduct = new SqlCommand($"UPDATE Product SET Остаток = @Ост WHERE Наименование = @Наименование", connection))
{
    updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ост", finRemains);
    updateProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Наименование", cellDataSet);
    updateProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)